# Remove only files and not the directory in linux

Tags: linux, directory

I want to know how I can remove all the files in a directory say **directory1** contains some 100 files. I just want to remove the files and not the directory.

I know that `rmdir directory1` will remove directory1 completely. But I want to only remove all the files inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rm /path/to/directory1/*
```

by adding the `-r` option you can additionally remove contained directories and their content recursively.

Answer (score 2):

```
  find /path/to/directory1 -type f | xargs rm -f
```

This recursively deletes all normal files in the directory.